# Why does Azure Media Services v3 job fail when submitting an encoded URL to JobInputHttp?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-media-services

When submitting urls to the JobInputHttp class to use an uploaded video as a media source, the job fails if the url is encoded because the file name has spaces?

For encoding I am just using encodeURI() to replace the spaces character with %20 using JavaScript before sending it to the web server.

File is uploaded to blob storage from client side. I am able to view the video from azure portal so it is being uploaded correctly. After the video is uploaded a stream attempts to be created by sending the encoded url and filename of the uploaded file to the backend before submitting to Azure Media Services (AZM).

Test Cases:

- Filename without spaces and meets naming conventions - Passes and viewable from AZM asset
- Filename contains spaces - Unsure if spaces meeting [AZM Asset naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/media-services-apis-overview#naming-conventions)

  - Returns 500 Error if not encoded
  - Job fails in azure portal when encoded with error "While trying to download the input files, the files were not accessible, please check the availability of the source", screenshot below.

[Failed Job Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzadW.png)

Current Code:

```
        private async Task<Job> SubmitJobAsync(IAzureMediaServicesClient client,
        string resourceGroup,
        string accountName,
        string transformName,
        string outputAssetName,
        string jobName,
        string url)
    {
        // This example shows how to encode from any HTTPs source URL - a new feature of the v3 API.  
        // Change the URL to any accessible HTTPs URL or SAS URL from Azure.
        JobInputHttp jobInput =
            new JobInputHttp(files: new[] { url });

        JobOutput[] jobOutputs =
        {
            new JobOutputAsset(outputAssetName),
        };

        // In this example, we are assuming that the job name is unique.
        //
        // If you already have a job with the desired name, use the Jobs.Get method
        // to get the existing job. In Media Services v3, the Get method on entities returns null 
        // if the entity doesn't exist (a case-insensitive check on the name).
        Job job = await client.Jobs.CreateAsync(
            resourceGroup,
            accountName,
            transformName,
            jobName,
            new Job
            {
                Input = jobInput,
                Outputs = jobOutputs,
            });

        return job;
    }
```

[Example using Azure Media Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/stream-files-tutorial-with-api)

- [Git Files](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-dotnet-tutorials)

[Example using JobInputHttp Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/job-input-from-http-how-to)

Answer (score 1):

Answer: The encodeURI() function was also encoding special characters within the [Shared Access Signature (SAS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview#sas-token) token submitted in the url.

I tested the submission using `<string>.replaceAll(' ', '%20')` and was able to get a passing AZM job. I ran the full URL through encodeURI() and compared the SAS Tokens and realized it changed `%253D` to `%25253D` based on [standard HTML encoding](https://krypted.com/utilities/html-encoding-reference/).

Testing code from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)

```
const encoded = encodeURI("%253D");
console.log('Encoded: ', encoded);
// expected output: "%25253D"

try {
  console.log('Decoded', decodeURI(encoded));
  // expected output: "%253D"
} catch (e) { // catches a malformed URI
  console.error(e);
}

// output
//"Encoded: " "%25253D"
//"Decoded" "%253D"
```

Because the URL was not being decoded before being submitted it was not able to locate the video source.

I guess I just needed to ask the question to get the answer. Real-life rubber ducky debugging :).