# How to prevent Azure Media Services Job from truncating input url unexpectedly with python client?

Tags: python, azure, azure-media-services

When submitting a job to Azure Media Services, I'm getting an error because the input url is being truncated unexpectedly.

```py
from msrestazure.azure_active_directory import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.media import AzureMediaServices, models

from django.conf import settings
from datetime import datetime

tenant_id = settings.AZURE_TENANT_ID
subscription_id = settings.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION
client_id = settings.AZURE_CLIENT_ID
client_secret = settings.AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET
resource_group_name = settings.AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP
account_name = settings.AZURE_MEDIA_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id, client_secret, tenant=tenant_id)

ams = AzureMediaServices(credentials, subscription_id)
preset = models.BuiltInStandardEncoderPreset(preset_name='H264MultipleBitrateSD')
transform_output = models.TransformOutput(preset=preset)
outputs = [transform_output]
transform_name = "Alfa"
transform =  ams.transforms.create_or_update(
   account_name=account_name, outputs=outputs, resource_group_name=resource_group_name, transform_name=transform_name
)
#### everything up to here is working as expected, but included for completeness ####

input_url = ("https://download-whatever.somewhere-dev.com/api/download/v1/blob?t=blahblah"
    "qaf8&c=qaf8&id=bf04fd7a-167a-4fa7-9e29-ed88525dd03b&et=20201117212714&isfullc"
    "ontainername=True&sig=nMEXM90SKC3imXnYrgb2bA9oMMSe6nh1mD6nrEnA4cE%3D"
    )
input = models.JobInputHttp(files=[input_url])
# input.files shows correct list with single correct url at this point
asset_name = "out-{}".format(datetime.utcnow().isoformat())
asset = ams.assets.create_or_update(resource_group_name, account_name, asset_name, {})
output = models.JobOutputAsset(asset_name=asset.name)
local_job = models.Job(input=input, outputs=[output])
# local_job.input.files shows the list of single correct url, too
job_name = "job-{}".format(datetime.utcnow().isoformat())
created_job = ams.jobs.create(resource_group_name, account_name, transform.name, job_name, local_job)
# created_job.input.files
#  [u'https://download-whatever.somewhere-dev.com/api/download/v1/blob']
# here's the problem--why is ^ truncated at the query params?
```

[The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-media/azure.mgmt.media.models.jobinputhttp?view=azure-python) say that if only `files` is specified, no transformation is to take place

> If no base uri is given, then the provided file list is assumed to be fully qualified uris.

Creating the input with `base_uri=u'https://download-whatever.somewhere-dev.com/api/download/v1/blob'` and `files=?t=blahblahqaf8&c=qaf8&id=bf04fd7a-167a-4fa7-9e29-ed88525dd03b&et=20201117212714&isfullcontainername=True&sig=nMEXM90SKC3imXnYrgb2bA9oMMSe6nh1mD6nrEnA4cE%3D"` yields the same result.

I have confirmed that the URL itself works and is accessible publicly--I'm able to download the file and it plays as expected.

After further debugging, I'm largely convinced this is not a programming issue at all, but has to do with AMS itself: I get more or less the same exact effect when I create the Job directly in the Azure portal, using both the names provided by the script and using the default values provided by the form in the portal.

So how does that URL get truncated? What can I do to prevent it?

Here is a standalone script that illustrates the issue. It uses a working URL with the generated SAS token. It does require an existing Transform called "MyTransform"

```py
from msrestazure.azure_active_directory import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.media import AzureMediaServices, models
from pprint import pprint

from time import time

from django.conf import settings # uncomment this if running in a Django environment with the correct values set

# class Settings:
#     """
#     These should be set for whatever your test environment is
#     """
#     AZURE_CLIENT_ID =
#     AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET =
#     AZURE_TRANSFORM_RESOURCE_GROUP =
#     AZURE_MEDIA_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME =
#     AZURE_TENANT =
#     AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION =
#
# settings = Settings()

client_id = settings.AZURE_CLIENT_ID
client_secret = settings.AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET
resource_group_name = settings.AZURE_TRANSFORM_RESOURCE_GROUP
account_name = settings.AZURE_MEDIA_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME
transform_name = 'MyTransform'
azure_tenant_id = settings.AZURE_TENANT_ID
azure_subscription_id = settings.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION

azure_credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id, client_secret, tenant=azure_tenant_id
)

ams =  AzureMediaServices(azure_credentials, azure_subscription_id)

input_url = "https://qamainms.blob.core.windows.net/asset-c4659a26-01fd-4fa8-a374-7afa212db59b/bf04fd7a-167a-4fa7-9e29-ed88525dd03b.mov?sp=r&st=2020-11-20T19:14:33Z&se=2021-01-01T03:14:33Z&spr=https&sv=2019-12-12&sr=b&sig=K2AW3luO6oqj4478aetFm9qgS%2FAa7Jd6zEXpfRcjsRE%3D"
input = models.JobInputHttp(files=[input_url])
timestamp = time()
asset_name = "perc-transcode-out-{:.4f}".format(timestamp).replace('.', '_')
asset = ams.assets.create_or_update(resource_group_name, account_name, asset_name, {})
asset.as_dict()
output = models.JobOutputAsset(asset_name=asset.name)
job = models.Job( input=input, outputs=[output])
job_name = "perc-transcode-job-{:.4f}".format(timestamp).replace('.', '_')
job = ams.jobs.create(resource_group_name, account_name, transform_name, job_name, job)
print("############ CREATED NEW JOB #####################\n"
       "with input_url: {}\n"
       "job name: {}\n"
       "job.input.files: {}\n"
       "#################################".format(input_url, job.name, job.input.files))
pprint(job.as_dict())
pprint("#################################")

ams.jobs.get(resource_group_name, account_name, transform_name, job_name)
new_job = ams.jobs.get(resource_group_name, account_name, transform_name, job_name)
print("############ FETCHED NEW JOB #####################\n"
       "with input_url: {}\n"
       "job name: {}\n"
       "job.input.files: {}\n"
       "#################################".format(input_url, new_job.name, new_job.input.files))
pprint(new_job.as_dict())
pprint("#################################")
assert new_job.input.files[0] == input_url, "Expected {}, but got {}".format(input_url, new_job.input.files[0])
print("File Input matches! No Problem Detected")
```

Comment: Can you be sure that your input_url is valid? Or is it accessible? It is recommended to upload a sample video, such as a.mp4 file, and you can play it in your broswer with sas token.

Comment: I'm able to download the .mov file (which a teammate uploaded) in my browser. The downloaded file plays back fine. The host i'm downloading from is publicly accessible. But even if it weren't, why would the query params be stripped?

Comment: sorry, Jason, your answer doesn't address my problem. On the one hand, using a link that works does allow the job to complete. On the other, I keep receiving truncated input urls. Unfortunately, I can't say that your answer has added anything to my understanding of the problem, though I do appreciate the effort.

Comment: I think the question you raised should be normal. It should be the normal way to use the sas token. In azure media services, the return value of `created_job.input.files` designed in the SDK should not contain the token parameter.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

**My previous attempts were just to reproduce your problem.**

Now I know what you want. You want the value of `created_job.input.files` equal `input_url`, right ?

**I read the SDK documentation, it should not be feasible. I guess the original design is to use sas to access the resource, and then return the url of the resource in the blob. When sas is used as a token, it will also expire, so returning the URL of the file storage is the most important.**

First of all, this is not the problem of azure media services as you described, we can grant limited access to Azure Storage resources using shared access signatures (SAS).

So you think that the truncated parameters, such as the sas token, will only return the Uri of the file in the blob after the SDK.

If you need further help, [you can raise a support ticket on portal to confirm this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).

**PRIVIOUS**

```
created_job = ams.jobs.create(RESOUCE_GROUP_NAME, ACCOUNT_NAME, transform.name, job_name, local_job)
print(created_job.input.files)
# created_job.input.files
```

*Result:*

[image]

So I guess the format of `input_url` is wrong, pls replace it and use my test url.

I search the answer in stackoverflow and test it by myself.

**Information that may be useful to you:**

[Why does Azure Media Services v3 job fail when submitting an encoded URL to JobInputHttp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64362008/why-does-azure-media-services-v3-job-fail-when-submitting-an-encoded-url-to-jobi)

**Test steps:**

I test the url you give, and it can't be played in broswer. I upload a test video to blob, and generate the url with sas token.

Like :

```
https://pajasomediastorage.blob.core.windows.net/asset-a6f42115-3d99-4322-b368-664a2f063821/movie.mp4?sp=r&st=2020-11-23T07:51:00Z&se=2020-11-23T15:51:00Z&spr=https&sv=2019-12-12&sr=b&sig=x0aj3BMAbMaQfv54cbrxo6X4AW8FDNZvFl5mtjcBYe4%3D
```

[image]

Then I replace the `job` to `local_job` in this line.

**Before:**

```
created_job = ams.jobs.create(resource_group_name, account_name, transform.name, job_name, job)
```

**After modified.**

```
created_job = ams.jobs.create(resource_group_name, account_name, transform.name, job_name, local_job)
```

And it works for me. So I think it must be something wrong in input_url.

You can check it in job status.

[image]

Hope my suggestion can help you. If you need further help me, please let me know.

[image]

Comment: hey thanks for trying this out. You're a little off-base, though. First, the url I'm passing IRL is not the one I posted, just an example of what the real one looks like. Second, uploading it to Azure blob storage, while I agree it "works", it doesn't actually solve my problem, because the task I have is to do this video encoding from the existing storage. Finally, while I have tried using the method you describe, I'm still seeing the URL truncation, even if the url in that case still works.

Comment: in your example, I'd also be interested in seeing the result of `created_job.input.files` for you -- does that input come back with the URL params truncated?

Comment: I have updated my answer, and show the result of `created_job.input.files` to you.